# How to use Future<bool> return value from function without async function (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

I wrote short flutter app that have a async function that get value from cloud firestore and return Future bool type according to the information from the database.
now in my main code I want to return a Widget according to the value that got return form that mention function, but I didn't succeed using the returned value right.
I tried to write an external async function that will call the first function and will put the returned value inside a shared variable. but it didn't work for me and got sometimes error about that variable isn't been initialized.

- it's looked like the code is not stopping line by line and wait for my function to return the value when been called and continue on the if statement.
- Someone know how can I return a widget according to the value that the function returning and fix that issue?.
- I tried using block of code using then but I never use it before so it doesn't worked as well.

my fist function:

```
Future<bool> firstFunc(String uid) async {
  DocumentSnapshot userData =
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').doc(uid).get();
  bool value = userData["param"];
  return value;
}
```

and this is my main code:

```
// imports

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: AuthenticationWrapper(),
    );
  }
}

class AuthenticationWrapper extends StatefulWidget {
  const AuthenticationWrapper({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _AuthenticationWrapperState createState() => _AuthenticationWrapperState();
}

class _AuthenticationWrapperState extends State<AuthenticationWrapper> {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  late bool sharedVar;

  void getValue(String uid) async {
    bool value = await firstFunc(uid);
    sharedVar = value;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_auth.currentUser != null) {
      getValue(_auth.currentUser!.uid);
      if (sharedVar == true)
      {
        return BossHomePage();
      }
      else {
        return ClientHomePage();
      }
    } else {
      return const EnterPhonePage();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Checkout [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it doesn't wait for `getValue` is that `getValue` is of type `void`.
Try this;

```dart
class AuthenticationWrapper extends StatefulWidget {
  const AuthenticationWrapper({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _AuthenticationWrapperState createState() => _AuthenticationWrapperState();
}

class _AuthenticationWrapperState extends State<AuthenticationWrapper> {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (_auth.currentUser != null) {
      return FutureBuilder<bool>(
      future: firstFunc(uid),
      builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot){
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            return const CircularProgressIndicator();

          case ConnectionState.none:
            return const Text('No data');

          case ConnectionState.active:
          case ConnectionState.done:
            if (snapshot.data == true) {
              return BossHomePage();
            } else {
              return ClientHomePage();
            }
          default:
          return const Text('No data');
        }
      },
    )
    } else {
      return const EnterPhonePage();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you it working. except the part that I need to add a custom waiting screen :).

Comment: You can replace `const CircularProgressIndicator()` with your custom waiting screen

Answer (score 1):

`getValue` is a future method, You need to use `async` at some point. You can convert this to

```dart
Future<bool> getValue(String uid) async {
    bool value = ....;
    return value;
  }
```

And use `FutureBuilder` (or `initState` is better SatefullWidget) for this case

```dart
 late bool sharedVar;
  Future<void> getValue(String uid) async {
    bool value =...;
    sharedVar = value;
  }

  bool? currentUser;
  
  _initData()async{
    getValue("");
    ///all others methods
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
   _initData();
  }
```

More about [async-await](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await)

Comment: what do you mean by "all other methods"?

Comment: if you have others method that is needed on initState, I prefer this way